# what is difference between spring social and spring security oauth

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

As far as i understand, I can get the same result about login for Facebook, Google,   and etc using both.
I searched a lot but nobody asked this...
What's difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Social is an extension of the Spring Framework that allows you to connect your applications with Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) API providers such as Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn. You may also check this site https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: I've already read it. see this two https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/core.html, https://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/. as you can see the features, you can do oauth2 with spring-social

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271118/6714134) about use of spring social instead of **plain oauth**, not Spring security oauth.

But as this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/03/spring-social-end-of-life-announcement) is described Spring social is in end of life.

> With the release of Spring Security 5, much of the functionality
>   offered by Spring Social’s connection framework, which is the most
>   valuable piece of Spring Social is now part of Spring Security

Probably you are speaking about spring-security-oauth2-client which part of spring security 5.

These links are some implementation with that:

https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/