# What is the relationship between Spring social and oauth2 protocol?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

I read some stuff about oauth2 protocol and its concepts like:

- resource owner
- resource server
- authorization server
- grant types and etc..

Does spring-social use oauth2 protocol?

For example if I want to have social login with facebook, what is the role of facebook, appTest,...
in oauth2 terms?

**UPDATE**

After a considerable amount of searching i found https://www.credera.com/blog/ecommerce/spring-social-alternative-oauth.

but i'm still confused about oauth2 concepts authorization server, resource server and ... in spring social.

Answer (score 0):

From the link in question:

> Oauth specification was first released in 2007, OAuth has been the
>   standard method of authentication for software-as-a-service providers.
>   OAuth provides the means for a client website to access user
>   information from a third party on behalf of the user, without
>   requiring the user to provide their login details. Unfortunately for
>   developers, implementing the OAuth handshake with various providers
>   can be quite tedious
>
> Spring Social, a project that drastically simplifies the process of
>   creating and managing third party provider connections. The goals of
>   the project are to abstract the specific implementation details of
>   each service to provide developers with a simple method of getting
>   each service’s API in a strongly-typed Java binding, and to cleanly
>   organize stored connections so that they can be associated with the
>   application’s local users.
>
> There are numerous benefits to using Spring Social instead of plain
>   OAuth. Spring Social handles all of the variants of the OAuth protocol
>   that are out on the web, and with its support of provider specific
>   modules, anyone can adapt it to connect to any OAuth enabled provider.
>   The framework provides built in connection storage and management, and
>   provides users with a Java-consumable API specifically tailored for
>   the service they are using.
>
> In addition, though Spring Social
>   currently relies on OAuth, it is not dependent on the protocol. Since
>   authorization protocols are completely abstracted from any exposed
>   connection details, no refactoring should be required when providers
>   inevitably change their authorization strategy.